# CORS request do not persist cookies

Tags: https, cors

I have CORS request which looks like this:

```
General
Request URL: https://example-be-app.com/auth/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: 111.111.111.111:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example-fe.com
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 109
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 14 Jun 2023 11:37:49 GMT
Expires: Wed, 14 Jun 2023 11:37:49 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Set-Cookie: ACCESS_GRANTED=true; Max-Age=86400; Expires=Thu, 15 Jun 2023 11:37:49 GMT; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: ACCESS_TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1oooooooooooooopppppppppppppppp2xsLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTY4Njc0MjY2OSwicm9sZXMiOlsiQWRtaW4iXSwiaXNzIjoiYXR0YWxhYiIsImV4cCI6MTY4NjgyOTA2OSwiaWF0IjoxNjg2NzQyNjY5LCJ1c2VySWQiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZG1pdHJpakBhdHRhcG9sbC5jb20ifQ.RGBIp6dkPyh5WW6-_RWgnoMBKxFBup6aJWJL99Y8zHc; Max-Age=86400; Expires=Thu, 15 Jun 2023 11:37:49 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly; SameSite=None
Vary: Origin
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 73d7d15cda23525456456w341342fd5d5f

Request Heades
:Authority: example-be-app.com
:Method: POST
:Path: /auth/login
:Scheme: https
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 55
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: ACCESS_GRANTED=true; ACCESS_TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzIooooooooooooooppppppppppppppppxsLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTY4Njc0MTk1OSwicm9sZXMiOlsiQWRtaW4iXSwiaXNzIjoiYXR0YWxhYiIsImV4cCI6MTY4NjgyODM1OSwiaWF0IjoxNjg2NzQxOTU5LCJ1c2VySWQiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZG1pdHJpakBhdHRhcG9sbC5jb20ifQ.H38oe1ORyjwO96-mHEk3FSWNUhUuJxTvcgft6eLR4vU
Origin: https://example-fe.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://example-fe.com/
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

client side should persist `ACCESS_GRANTED` and `ACCESS_TOKEN` in a cookies storage, but it didn't.

In devtools I don't see any errors and I don't understand why these cookies don't persisted. May be I mist any headers?
Also in localhost everything works fine as expected. for request I'm using axios with config where I'm setting `withCredentials: true`.
Thanks for any help!